# Regex for URL ending with optional /

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting, iis-7

I am looking for a Regex pattern to match the following -

```
https://www.example.org
https://www.example.org/abc
```

if the string has a trailing `/`, pattern should ignore it and not add it to the match.
If there are any query string parameters, It should return the string as is.

I tried ^(.*)(?:/)?$ but this is not ignoring the trailing '/'

Comment: What was that you tried and how exactly didn't it work? Where are you using the regex?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to do?

Comment: Assuming you only have a URL (not trying to extract it from other text), you can make it fail if it has a trailing `/` using this Regex: `(?!.*\/$).*`

Comment: I have to extract the URL Druzion. Not fail it.

Comment: Please check if it works for you, https://regex101.com/r/eD5rR0/4

Comment: @Wiktor - I need to use this as a part of URL rewrite in order to redirect to the correct default pages if my users are not specifying it.

Comment: @Bharath: I think you can use [`https?:\/\/\S*+(?<!\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6vY3/1) or even `https?:\/\/.*+(?<!\/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, "ignoring" seems to mean "do not match if a trailing slash is found".

You can use an equivalent version with a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*/$)(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE7kG1/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*/$)` - check if the string does not end with `/` and if yes, fail the match
- `(.*)` - match and capture into Group 1 (`{R:1}`) the whole string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: When I try the above patterns in IIS rewrite module, I get an error - The expression contains a repeatable character - *, +, .. not preceeded by an expression. This however works fine in Regex101.

Comment: So, it is a .NET module? Use atomic group: `^(?>.+)(?<!\/)` or `^(?>.+)(?<!\/)`

Comment: ^(?>.+)(?<!\/) or ^(?>.+)(?<!\/) both looks to be the same. Also, IIs says "Expression syntax is incorrect". I am using IIS7 if that helps.

Comment: It is becoming very curious. I added a lookahead based solution: [`^(?!.*/$)(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/dC7jL1/3).